# How to make shuffle in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, shuffle, data-masking

Let's suppose I have a mysql database with sensitive information and I would like to make a shuffle on some data such as swapping values from the lastname column by values from the same column only from another user.

Note: the database will be used by the developers and I do not want them to have access to the true information so those suggestions using select would not solve, I saw that Soft DataVeil does this but not in mysql

Example
User1 receives lastname from user4

Orginal data

```
Fristname    | Lastname
user1        |   lastname1
user2        |   lastname2
user3        |   lastname 3
user4        |   lastname4
user5        |   lastname5
```

Shuffle mode

```
Fristname    |  Lastname
user1        |  lastname4
user2        |  lastname5 
user3        |  lastname2
user4        |  lastname1
user5        |  lastname3
```

Note: I tried to use the dataveil for this but apparently it does not do shuffle in mysql

Comment: if it does not matter to get duplicates in the Lastname column i've posted a possible answer.

Comment: "Frist!"" Might want to fix that typo before it gets fossilized.

Comment: thanks but those options using select would not solve since the dev should not see the true information

I edited the post to clarify my doubts.

Comment: If you don't want developers to see the "true" full name, why are you returning it all?

Comment: 1st the information I used for example is just an example, the same bank has other values like phone, cpf etc ...

2. The Shuffle technique uses the already stored values of column x and changes the order of the same column x

3rd, I can not change the bank structure


In the case this has to do with masking of information,

Answer (score 2):

If you dont mind duplicates in the Lastname column 
You can do it with a simple subquery with a random order and limit.

**Query**

```
SELECT
   Table1.Fristname
 , (SELECT Table11.Lastname FROM Table1 AS Table11 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS  Lastname
FROM 
 Table1
```

**Possible result**

```
| Fristname | Lastname   |
| --------- | ---------- |
| user1     | lastname 3 |
| user2     | lastname 3 |
| user3     | lastname 3 |
| user4     | lastname5  |
| user5     | lastname4  |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v4M9YodwnnxnfPekZQ2DG5/5)

Comment: thanks but those options using select would not solve since the dev should not see the true information

I edited the post to clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use session variables to get row number.
- In two separate derived tables, get `Fristname`, and `Lastname` (latter one being randomly ordered).
- Join them both on the row number. Since `Lastname` is randomly ordered, you will get different `Lastname` for a `Fristname`.
- **This approach will ensure No Duplicates in the `Lastname` column**

**All versions of MySQL**: Try something like this  (**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0aeba/5)**):

```
SELECT t3.Fristname,
       t4.Lastname 
    FROM ( 
           SELECT @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS rn1, 
                  t1.Fristname  
           FROM your_table AS t1 
           CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn1 := 0) AS rnt1 
         ) AS t3 
    INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS rn2, 
                        t5.Lastname 
                 FROM 
                 ( 
                   SELECT t2.Lastname 
                   FROM your_table AS t2 
                   ORDER BY rand()
                 ) AS t5
                  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn2 := 0) AS rnt2
                ) AS t4 ON t4.rn2 = t3.rn1
```

Comment: Nice + 1 but you don't have to use `SET` twice by the way see this approach https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v4M9YodwnnxnfPekZQ2DG5/1.. This saves you two doing the `SET` queries.

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks - updated to remove usage of `set`

Comment: there is also a (very) small chance in this approach it wont shuffle all records and keep the non shuffled the same as the source data..

Comment: @RaymondNijland True but will happen rarely in most practical scenarios; assuming that OP has big dataset of atleast 1000s of rows, chances of this to happen will be very less.